# Java replace not working as expected

Tags: java, string, replace

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String original="r(1,2,1)=r(1,2,0)+r(1,1,0)r(1,1,0)*r(1,2,0)";
        StringTest strtest=new StringTest();
        strtest.setX(original.replace("r(1,2‚0)", "TEST"));
        System.out.println(original.replace("r(1,2,0)", "TEST"));
        System.out.println(strtest);
    }
}

class StringTest {
    String x=null;

    public StringTest() {}

    public String toString() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String other) {
        x=other;
    }
}
```

Running this gives output:

```
r(1,2,1)=TEST+r(1,1,0)r(1,1,0)*TEST
r(1,2,1)=r(1,2,0)+r(1,1,0)r(1,1,0)*r(1,2,0)
```

Why is `x` in `strtest` equal to `original` string and r(1,2,0) is not replaced and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

And why doesnt it work in this code, grep couldnt find any non-ascii symbols in this file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

public class DFK {
    static ArrayList<Path> done = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public static void print() {
        for(Path i: done) {
            //System.out.println(i+"  "+i.isConverted());
            if(i.isConverted()) {
                System.out.println(i.getConverted());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void develop() {
        if(done.get(0).getKP1() > 0) {
            DFK.add(new Path(done.get(0).getP(), done.get(0).getQ(), done.get(0).getK()));
            DFK.add(new Path(done.get(0).getP(), done.get(0).getKP1(), done.get(0).getK()));
            DFK.add(new Path(done.get(0).getKP1(), done.get(0).getKP1(), done.get(0).getK()));
            DFK.add(new Path(done.get(0).getKP1(), done.get(0).getQ(), done.get(0).getK()));
        }
    }

    public static void add(Path x) {
            boolean exists = (done.indexOf(x)==-1 ? false : true);
            if(exists == false) {
                done.add(x);
                if(x.getKP1() >= 2) {
                    DFK.add(new Path(x.getP(), x.getQ(), x.getK()));
                    DFK.add(new Path(x.getP(), x.getKP1(), x.getK()));
                    DFK.add(new Path(x.getKP1(), x.getKP1(), x.getK()));
                    DFK.add(new Path(x.getKP1(), x.getQ(), x.getK()));
                }
            }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int p = 0, q = 0, kp1 = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("p = ");p = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("q = ");q = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("k+1 = ");kp1 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\n");
        String rkzero[][] = new String[q][q];
        for(int i=0; i<q ; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<q ; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("r(%d,%d,0): ", i+1, j+1));
                rkzero[i][j]=input.readLine();
            }
        }

        done.add(new Path(p, q, kp1));
        DFK.develop();
        Collections.sort(done);

        for(int z=0; z<q ; z++) {
            for(int j=0; j<q ; j++) {
                for(Path i: done) {
                        String reg = String.format("r(%d,%d,0)",z+1,j+1);
                        i.setConverted(i.toString().replace( reg , rkzero[z][j])); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        DFK.print();
    }
}

class Path implements Comparable<Path> {
    int p,q,kplus1,k;
    String converted = null;

    public int getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public int getQ() {
        return q;
    }

    public int getKP1() {
        return kplus1;
    }

    public int getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public Path(int a, int b, int c) {
        super();
        p = a;
        q = b;
        kplus1 = c;
        k = c-1;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Path.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        final Path other = (Path) obj;
        if(other.p == this.p && other.q == this.q && other.kplus1 == this.kplus1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int compareTo(Path other) {
        return other.kplus1-kplus1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("r(%d,%d,%d)=r(%d,%d,%d)+r(%d,%d,%d)r(%d,%d,%d)*r(%d,%d,%d)",p,q,kplus1,p,q,k,p,kplus1,k,kplus1,kplus1,k,kplus1,q,k);
    }

    public void setConverted(String x) {
        converted = new String(x);
    }

    public String getConverted() {
        return converted;
    }

    public boolean isConverted() {
        if(converted == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
p = 1
q = 2
k+1 = 2

r(1,1,0): 0
r(1,2,0): 1
r(2,1,0): 1
r(2,2,0): 0

r(1,2,2)=r(1,2,1)+r(1,2,1)r(2,2,1)*r(2,2,1)
r(1,2,1)=r(1,2,0)+r(1,1,0)r(1,1,0)*r(1,2,0)
r(2,2,1)=0+r(2,1,0)r(1,1,0)*r(1,2,0)
```

It replaces only r(2,2,0) with 0 and nothing else, I replicated previous problem from this, but I can't find any non-asci symbols in this one.

Comment: You should take more care when using your keyboard. The second comma between 2 and 0 in the first `replace` call is not the usual comma. Just rewrite that and it should work. Close to vote this question as typo.

Comment: How did this happen, what other comma did I use

Comment: @Nebeski your original question was answered, and it's almost being closed. If you have another question, please ask it in another, separate question.

Comment: @JBNizet I posted a new question, if you could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last comma in your first "r(1,2‚0)" string is not a standard comma (with decimal value 44). Instead, it's [another special character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm), but which looks exactly the same, with decimal value 8218. Just erase that character and replace it with a comma, and it will work as expected.

An easy way to detect such bizarre characters is to print their decimal value. For example:

```
String target = "r(1,2‚0)";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(target.chars().toArray()));
```

which prints

```
[114, 40, 49, 44, 50, 8218, 48, 41]
```

You can clearly see here that the problematic character is out of the range of basic ASCII characters.

Comment: Typo -> close or do you assume someone else with this same typo will find this question?

Comment: @Tom I feel that this question would mislead others with its title.

Comment: @JacobG. This whole question is not useful for somebody else and therefore doesn't belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If we only answered questions that could help other people, there are a whole lot of questions we would not answer. That's not a valid criteriion to answer a question or not. And I would not qualify this as a typo.

Comment: I know what you mean with "we" and these people answer every question they see, I know that, but that's not the purpose of Stack Overflow. And if you think it isn't a typo, then I wonder what your suggestion is how that char got there. Do you assume OP copies his commas?

Comment: Yes, that's what I assume. Or that he/she used a text editor or office suite typing such a bizarre character without knowing about it. Hence the question. What exactly is your problem with answering a valid, on-topic question with a valid answer? That's the whole point of this site. And, FYI, I reached the daily cap, so this answer doesn't even give me any rep point.

Comment: I used a text editor I always use, Sublime. And I got this problem from my other code in which I can't fix it as I did here, I even found a converter to ascii and still it doesnt work. How do you find those special characters?

Comment: You just descriped what a typo is "typing such a bizarre character without knowing about it". If it was OP himself/herself or a program doesn't matter for that and no, typo question are not on-topic.

Comment: @Tom If you type "Top" instead of "Tom", I can tell you "hey look, you have typo there", and you will say "Oh, yes, of course: I mistyped Tom". That's far from being the case here. The OP can't even notice there is an unwanted character, and the editor inserted it instead of the correct character that the OP wanted. Will you please move along with your life? You've casted your close vote, you've downvoted, we disagree. The world won't collapse because a question was answered.